# How to find out the language that accepted by below NPDA

Tags: computer-science, automata, automata-theory

I wanna understand how find the language that will be accepted by below NPDA.

```
M = {Q, Σ, Τ, δ, q0, z, F}
Q is a set of state: {q0, q1, q2}
Σ is alphabet: {a, b}
Τ is stack alphabet: {0, 1, z}
δ is transition function
z is stack start symbol
F is set of final state.
```

And, it's transition function is below.

```
δ(q0, a, z) = {(q1 , 0), (q2 , λ)}
δ(q1, b, 0) = {(q1, 1)}
δ(q1, b, 1) = {(q1, 1)}
δ(q1, a, 1) = {(q2, λ)}
```

Comment: It's impossible to say what language this NPDA accepts without seeing the transitions. What is the transition function?

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to write the transition function.

Comment: Is the result of executing transition f(q0, a, z) = (q1, 0) a stack with just a zero in it, or a zero and the bottom-of-stack symbol? is it "0" or "0z"? The notation used suggests the former to me but just want to be sure.

Comment: Yes it is. Former is right. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on these transitions, I will assume that the final state is q2 and it accepts with empty stack (it looks like it gets rid of even the bottom-of-stack symbol z, which is a little unusual for me, but I guess it's fine).

The transitions are these:

```
δ(q0, a, z) = {(q1 , 0), (q2 , λ)}
δ(q1, b, 0) = {(q1, 1)}
δ(q1, b, 1) = {(q1, 1)}
δ(q1, a, 1) = {(q2, λ)}
```

Let's take them one at a time.

1. `δ(q0, a, z) = {(q1 , 0), (q2 , λ)}` means that if we're in the initial state and we see an `a`, we can either go to state `q1` and replace `z` with `0`, or we can get rid of `z` and go to state `q2`. This is actually the accepting configuration for the NPDA; that means the NPDA accepts the empty string, and whatever language we determine must also contain that string. Because the only other way out of the initial state `q0` is to see an `a`, we also know that any non-empty strings in our language must begin with `a`.
2. `δ(q1, b, 0) = {(q1, 1)}` means that if we are now in state `q1`, see a `b` in the input and have `0` on top of the stack, we can change the stack symbol to `1`. We will be in this configuration as soon as we get to state `q1` from `q0`. Note that since no other transition puts a `0` on top of the stack, this is the only time this transition can be used; and indeed it must be used since `q1` is not accepting and we must come through this transition to clear the `0` off the top of the stack. So, all strings in the language which are non-empty must begin with `ab`.
3. `δ(q1, b, 1) = {(q1, 1)}` means that if we're in state `q1`, see a `b` in the input and have a `1` on top of the stack, we can consume more `b`s forever. We will remain in this configuration as long as we have more `b` in the input. We do not necessarily need to come through this state, however: there are other transitions that put `1` on top of the stack and the path to the accepting state may not involve this transition at all. This transition lets us put as many `b`s as we want after the one required `b` we saw in the last transition.
4. `δ(q1, a, 1) = {(q2, λ)} means that if we're in state`q1`, see an`a`in the input and have a`1`on top of the stack, we can erase the stack and go to the accepting state. This means that any non-empty string in the language ends with a single`a`.

To recap:

1. the empty string is in the language
2. any non-empty string in the language begins with `ab`
3. any non-empty string in the language can have an arbitrary number of `b`s in the middle
4. any non-empty string in the language ends with `a`.

Putting this all together, we find a regular expression describes the language: `e + abb*a`. We should not be surprised by this since this NPDA's stack only ever contains zero to two elements in it; because the amount of stack used is constant, the NPDA is equivalent to some DFA and therefore its language must be regular.